# Thinking sphinx - exclude classes if field isn't present in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm doing an application search that might filter on several different fields - some of which are not present in every index.

At the moment sorting out the correct classes to search on in the controller, using a complicated if elsif elsif thing.

Is there a way to get thinking sphinx to automatically not search a model if one a condition field isn't present, rather than ignoring the condition as seems to happen at the moment.

Eg

```
 ThinkingSphinx.search(@query, :conditions => {:genres =>"classical-music"}, :match_mode => :extended, :classes => [Performer, Promoter, Tour, Venue, User], :order => :name_sort, :sort_mode => :asc)
```

User doesn't have genres, but is included in the search results

---

update

It definitely doesn't work as I'd like. My user model doesn't have the genres field in the index, so I'd like it to be excluded when I search on genres.

Example searches

```
User.search("anne")
  Sphinx Query (3.6ms)  anne
  Sphinx  Found 1 result
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (80)
 => [#<User id: 80, first_name: "Anne", last_name: "Bowers", bio: nil, email: "anne@bowers.com", phone: nil, created_at: "2012-11-20 09:36:05", updated_at: "2012-11-20 09:36:05", role: nil, promoter_id: nil, performer_id: nil, job_title: nil>] 


ThinkingSphinx.search("anne", :conditions => {:genres => "music"}, :match_mode => :extended, :classes => [User], :order => :name_sort, :sort_mode => :asc)
  Sphinx Query (3.2ms)  anne @genres music
  Sphinx  Found 1 result
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (80)
 => [#<User id: 80, first_name: "Anne", last_name: "Bowers", bio: nil, email: "anne@bowers.com", phone: nil, created_at: "2012-11-20 09:36:05", updated_at: "2012-11-20 09:36:05", role: nil, promoter_id: nil, performer_id: nil, job_title: nil>]
```

It'd be really good if the user was excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass classes to search in params.

But your way should work too i think.

For me

```
ThinkingSphinx.search(conditions: { type: "text" })
```

it just writes an error

> Sphinx Daemon returned warning: index bulletin_core,bulletin_delta,user_delta ...: query error: no field 'type' found in schema

but it doesnt crash. It returns only instances of classes which have indexed field `type`

You also can try a way which is written here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/thinking-sphinx/rrAPXtxUMjg but I haven't tryed it yet

Comment: If you add a string query as well as the condition, the conditions get ignored - see my update.

Comment: it's strange, because when i try to
```ThinkingSphinx.search('Savanna', conditions: { type: "Text" }, classes: [User])
```
it writes an error ```Sphinx Daemon returned error: index user_core,user_delta: query error: no field 'type' found in schema```

And do not return any results

Comment: so I think that passing classes with params it's good idea, for example, you can store this parameter at hidden field, and change it via javascript on some javascript events